# "Внутри смешались боль с морфином" или "Внутри смешалось боль с морфином"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

В песне придумал строчку. Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли разница и как правильно написать:
"Контроль утерян и внутри смешал**и**сь боль с морфином" или
"Контроль утерян и внутри смешал**о**сь боль с морфином".

Comment: Ну в песне можно как угодно коверкать слова. Можно смешалось. Через точку. Контроль утерян. И внутри смешалось. Боль с морфином. ...

Answer (score 3):

"Смешалось" - однозначно нет. В этом предложении нет ни одного слова, с которым можно было бы согласовать такую форму.
А вот "смешались" или "смешалась" - здесь все зависит от того, на чем делается акцент.

Если акцент делается на самом процессе смешивания (и речь идет о двух равнозначных ингредиентах этого процесса), то "смешал**и**сь":

> Контроль утерян и внутри
> Смешались боль с морфином.

Если же необходимо сделать акцент на **боли** (что позволит добавить экспрессии стихотворению), то лучше написать "смешал**а**сь":

> Контроль утерян и внутри
> Смешалась боль с морфином.

Comment: Запятую добавить бы перед союзом "и".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, я просто сохранил авторскую пунктуацию. А так, в принципе, я бы там возможно даже точку поставил.